# change iterrows() to .loc for large dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, data-wrangling

I have 2 data frames, df1 and df2.

Based on the condition in `df1` that `day_of_week == 7` we have to match 2 other column values,  `(statWeek and statMonth)`  if the condition matches then we have to replace `as_cost_perf` from df2 with `cost_eu` from df1. in other places we simply keep as_cost_perf as it is.

Below is my code block with iterrows()

in case, I have a huge dataframe it will be time consuming, can someone please help me optimize this snippet?

```
import pandas as pd

# create df1
data1 = {'day_of_week': [7, 7, 6],
         'statWeek': [1, 2, 3],
         'statMonth': [1, 1, 1],
         'cost_eu': [957940.0, 942553.0, 1177088.0]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

# create df2
data2 = {'statWeek': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3],
         'statMonth': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
         'as_cost_perf': [344560.0, 334580.0, 334523.0, 556760.0, 124660.0, 124660.0, 763660.0]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# identify rows in df1 where day_of_week == 7
mask = df1['day_of_week'] == 7

# update df2 with cost_eu from df1 where there is a match
for i, row in df1[mask].iterrows():
    matching_rows = df2[(df2['statWeek'] == row['statWeek']) & (df2['statMonth'] == row['statMonth'])]
    if not matching_rows.empty:
        df2.loc[matching_rows.index, 'as_cost_perf'] = row['cost_eu']

# print the updated df2
df2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just for my information, `merge` is the fastest solution on your real dataframe?

Comment: All three solutions are great and somehow take the same time, but we need df2 as output without disturbing future values of as_cost_perf :) I know I can simply remove the extra columns with null values and can get the same output with your solution too. Thanks for that, maybe for even bigger data frame that works even better :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks to answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `for` loop you can apply [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with single reassignment:

```
mask = df1['day_of_week'] == 7
df2 = df2.merge(df1[mask], on=['statWeek', 'statMonth'], how='left')
matched = ~df2['cost_eu'].isna()
df2.loc[matched, 'as_cost_perf'] = df2.loc[matched, 'cost_eu']
df2.drop(['day_of_week', 'cost_eu'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

---

```
   statWeek  statMonth  as_cost_perf
0         1          1      957940.0
1         2          1      942553.0
2         3          1      334523.0
3         4          1      556760.0
4         1          2      124660.0
5         2          2      124660.0
6         3          2      763660.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reformat `df1` and concatenate it with `df2` then drop duplicates:

```
upd = df1[df1['day_of_week'].eq(7)].rename(columns={'cost_eu': 'as_cost_perf'}).drop(columns='day_of_week')
out = pd.concat([upd, df2], axis=0).drop_duplicates(['statWeek', 'statMonth'])
```

To avoid `drop_duplicates`, you can simply remove the same rows from `df2`:

```
upd = df1[df1['day_of_week'].eq(7)].rename(columns={'cost_eu': 'as_cost_perf'}).drop(columns='day_of_week')

cols = ['statWeek', 'statMonth']
m = ~df2[cols].isin(upd[cols]).all(axis=1)
out = pd.concat([upd, df2.loc[m]], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   statWeek  statMonth  as_cost_perf
0         1          1      957940.0
1         2          1      942553.0
2         3          1      334523.0
3         4          1      556760.0
4         1          2      124660.0
5         2          2      124660.0
6         3          2      763660.0

>>> upd
   statWeek  statMonth  as_cost_perf
0         1          1      957940.0
1         2          1      942553.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `merge` or `update` but first we need filter `df1` since you only care about `day_of_week == 7` by doing `df1.loc[df1['day_of_week'].eq(7), 'statWeek':]`

## [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
df2.merge(df1.loc[df1['day_of_week'].eq(7), 'statWeek':],
          on=['statWeek', 'statMonth'], how='left')

   statWeek  statMonth  as_cost_perf   cost_eu
0         1          1      344560.0  957940.0
1         2          1      334580.0  942553.0
2         3          1      334523.0       NaN
3         4          1      556760.0       NaN
4         1          2      124660.0       NaN
5         2          2      124660.0       NaN
6         3          2      763660.0       NaN
```

## [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
# we need to set the index if we use update
df2 = df2.set_index(['statWeek', 'statMonth'])
# we set the index for df1.loc[...] and rename the cost_eu column to match df2
df2.update(df1.loc[df1['day_of_week'].eq(7), 'statWeek':]\
           .set_index(['statWeek', 'statMonth']).rename(columns={'cost_eu': 'as_cost_perf'}))

print(df2.reset_index())

   statWeek  statMonth  as_cost_perf
0         1          1      957940.0
1         2          1      942553.0
2         3          1      334523.0
3         4          1      556760.0
4         1          2      124660.0
5         2          2      124660.0
6         3          2      763660.0
```